# Apache Camel - Issue a HTTP-Request from within a Processor

Tags: java, integration, apache-camel

a similar, but more general question has been asked here:
[Business logic in Camel processors vs service endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413045/business-logic-in-camel-processors-vs-service-endpoints).

Now consider the following flow (E1 and E2 represent processors, they are not endpoints as in camel flows), which I trigger with parameters *(p,q)*:

```
Route: E1 -> E2
```

*E1* itself issues an HTTP-request with parameters *(p,q)*, receives the response-data *d* (sync) and forwards this to *E2*, which continues processing based on *(p,q,d)*. So it essentially enriches the input with additional data.

The endpoint, which is called contains the data that is to be integrated, i.e. this will not change and needs not to be configurable in the future.

I tried two solutions, both of which seem kind of wrong to me:

- use `http4:url` endpoints and piggyback the *(p,q)* in the header of the messages (or alternatively properties of the exchange).
- use a processor that explicitly/programmatically issues the http-request, processes the response and forwards the expected *(p,q,d)*. For convenience, I did this with a `producerTemplate` being sent to `http4:url` inside the camel-context.

Problem with the first is that it adds a lot of boilerplate procducers etc and make the actual route really obscure. The second approach allows to offload processing into a new class (and not mix it into the routes) but still requires the camel-context and depends on this.

What is the recommendation for this. I couldn't find anything around except more abstract statements like "do not mix business logic with wiring" etc.

*** added real use-case ***

E1 gets two dates (a time-span) and a department name, fetches all names that have been in the specified department over the specified time-span. Then (above I ignored this detail) the names are splitted and for every single name, all data is fetched that has been saved in the specified date-span. For this last step the dates from the input of the first is needed (so these need to be passed through the entire route).

thanks,
markus

Comment: Are you talking about enriching a message at E2, then take a look at the content enricher EIP

Comment: I want to enrich it in E1 and forward it to E2. Perhaps I should mention that E1 and E2 aren't endpoints but processors -- i added the real use-case

Comment: Essentially it is an enricher that I need. But here my problem is how to implement the Processor that implementments this enrichment, i.e. if it's ok to use templateProducer inside a Processor? Or should I try to make this processor independent from the camel-context.

Comment: You can enrich the message anyhow you like. Camel doesn't really care. If you use a processor / pojo its just java code and you can do whatever you want. If you use the enrich / pollEnrich DSL then they uses an AggregationStrategy to "merge" the enrichment.

Comment: I see no issue using a producer template inside the processor. It's a matter of taste - obviously the route will be easier to visualize if you use mostly DSL but if it's awkward to implement using DSL/EIP constructs resort to a processor - Camel does not really care how you do it.

Comment: thanks, then I'll go with the enricher to make the intention explicit

Comment: Can you mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Claus:

> You can enrich the message anyhow you like. Camel doesn't really care. If you use a processor / pojo its just java code and you can do whatever you want. If you use the enrich / pollEnrich DSL then they uses an AggregationStrategy to "merge" the enrichment.

I enriched the original input of the route by the result of the http4:url endpoint. This way I could separate the "fetching" of data from the acual business logic, which now happens in the Processor/AggregationStreategy bean that is independent of the rest (of camel in particular).

thanks
markus